# How to use systemless root on android

Tags: android, root

I have an app that helps locate your lost android phone and for rooted phones I have a one click convert to system app feature (so it will survive a factory reset).

Now some of my users complains and say it no longer works on devices that uses systemless root. So questions of the day are:

1. how do I detect if a user has systemless installed programmatically?
2. how do I use systemless? I guess it is not through the normal SU command

BR. Theis

Comment: The question of the day is: what is systemless root?

Comment: Another way to root your phone which apparently are mainstream now: http://www.howtogeek.com/249162/what-is-systemless-root-on-android-and-why-is-it-better/

Comment: Thank you. Very informaive pages.

Answer (score 0):

1. Well, I had one of my users do some tests on his phone and a simple call like this will tell you if the user has su installed:

   which su
2. Yes, the new systemless root also uses "su" as a command. Details can be found on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=68993733&postcount=7410)

Comment: `this will tell you if the user has su installed:`. Nice. But you asked something different. You asked `how do I detect if a user has systemless installed`.